# Разное отображение результатов в разных андроид-устройствах

Tags: phonegap, sqlite, javascript

запускаю пример кода с сайта [фонгап](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
    }
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

</script>
```

</head>
  <body>

</body>
</html>
В виртуальных машинах и на смартфонах друзей все запускается нормально выдает результат:

Demo table: 2 rows found. Row = 0 ID = 1 Data = First rowRow=1 ID = 2 Data = Second row

У меня на смартфоне код почему то зацикливается.

Выдает 
Demo table: 0 rows found. Demo table: 1 rows found. Row = 0 ID = 1 Data = First rowDemo table: 2 rows found. Row = 0 ID = 1 Data = First rowRow=1 ID = 2 Data = Second rowRow=1 ID = 2 Data = Second row

На моем смартфоне ICS, но на виртуалке тоже ICS и там отображается норм. В чем проблема?

Comment: Как я заметил, db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);выполняется столько раз, сколько строк находится в функции populateDB(tx). Почему программа себя так ведет?

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось сделать следующим образом

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   {
  // Wait for Cordova to load
 //
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 // Populate the database 
    //
     function populateDB(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
  var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);}

   // Query the database
      //
    function queryDB(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
   }

   // Query the success callback
  //
  function querySuccess(tx, results) {
  var len = results.rows.length;
 console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
 for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " +                        results.rows.item(i).data);
      }
  }

  // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
     console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
   }

    // Transaction success callback
     //
    function successCB() {

 }

   // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
      }
              }
  </script>
 </head> <body>
```